# Custom Rmarkdown syntax highlighting in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to add syntax higlighting for custom markdown in RStudio. Let's say I want text surrounded by `<-- -->` to be assigned one of the styles in the current rstheme (similarly to how, in an Rmd file opened in RStudio, text between `* *` gets the style for the `.ace_constant.ace_language` class). Any suggestions on how to do this?
Many thanks!